# Failed to determine Java version for profile jdk7-plugin-fix-version @ org.apache.commons:commons-parent:42

Tags: java, maven, liferay, maven-2, maven-3

I am facing the below error on maven build.

**Failed to determine Java version for profile jdk7-plugin-fix-version @ org.apache.commons:commons-parent:42
    problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5**

Please help to resolve this issue.

Full pom file present as below the issue comes when I am using apache.commons.lang3:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>LEP</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.esspl.lep2</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.esspl.lep2</groupId>
<artifactId>PMS</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>PMS</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
<configuration>
<autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
<appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
<appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
<appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir><liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
<pluginName>PMS-portlet</pluginName>
<pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.5</version>
<configuration>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<source>1.7</source>
<target>1.7</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
        <plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<configuration>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<modules>
<module>PMS-portlet</module>
<module>PMS-portlet-service</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
<artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
<version>${liferay.version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
<artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Additional dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>asm</groupId>
<artifactId>asm</artifactId>
<version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
<!--<dependency>
<groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
<groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-el</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-el</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
</dependency> -->
<!-- <dependency>
<groupId>commons-jexl</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-jexl</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.5</version>
</dependency>  -->
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- <dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
<artifactId>gson</artifactId>
<version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency> -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
<version>2.1.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.el</groupId>
<artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!--<dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId> <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jboss.el</artifactId> 
<version>2.0.0.GA</version> </dependency> -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.el</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-el</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
<version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
<version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
<version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
<version>1.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
<artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
<version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
<artifactId>jxls-core</artifactId>
<version>0.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jxls</groupId>
<artifactId>jxls-reader</artifactId>
<version>0.9.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>liferay-faces-bridge-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>liferay-faces-bridge-impl</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>liferay-faces-portal</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.liferay.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>liferay-faces-util</artifactId>
<version>3.1.3-ga4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-contrib</artifactId>
<version>3.1-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
<artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
<version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
<artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
<version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.esspl.lep2</groupId>
<artifactId>LEP-PMS-DTO</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.esspl.lep2</groupId>
<artifactId>LEP-Common</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.esspl.lep2</groupId>
<artifactId>Mail</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You seemed to be having a profile in your build....but without a full pom file  etc. and full log output it's impossible to say/guess what's wrong...

Comment: @khmarbaise Added full pom file. Yes, we have a profile in the build. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you please correctly format that...otherwise it's really hard to read.